# Controlling Main Camera with xBox Controller (MRTK & Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

Hi we (myself and my students) are using MRTK in Unity to build simple VR games.

We are trying to get the xBox Controller to move the player (or in MRTK terms I think to move the scene around the camera which is fixed at 0,0,0).

I've set up the controller and played with the MRTK settings but no luck.

My controller works perfectly in Windows Mixed Reality Portal but goes dead when the game loads.

Any help on the exact steps/settings in the MRTK editor window is appreciated.

Ben

Comment: If there is an error message, could you post it so that we can locate the problem?

Comment: Hi, could you please give a little bit more detail about your repro steps? When you say "controller" do you mean your xbox controller? What code are you using to listen for events? What do you expect to happen, what is actually happening?

Comment: Update: Using the default controller porfile and a new official wireless Xbox controller. If HP WMR headset is plugged in you you play the game controller does not teleport (move terrain). If the the HP WMR headset is unplugged and you play the game controller moves the camera?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to solve here:

1. How to move the player. Answer: Use `MixedRealityPlayspace.Transform.Translate`
2. How to respond to gamepad input. Answer: you can use Unity's [Input.GetAxis](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) to figure out which buttons / joysticks are pressed, however I found it a bit easier to use the [controller mappings](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/Input/InputActions.html) in MRTK to map the "navigation action" to the gamepad dpad and joysticks, and then listen for input changed on navigation events.

You can use the following code to move the MR Playspace using gamepad:

```
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input;
using Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Utilities;
using UnityEngine;

/// <summary>
/// Moves the player around the world using the gamepad, or any other input action that supports 2D axis.
/// 
/// We extend InputSystemGlobalHandlerListener because we always want to listen for the gamepad joystick position
/// We implement InputHandler<Vector2> interface in order to receive the 2D navigation action events.
/// </summary>
public class MRPlayspaceMover : InputSystemGlobalHandlerListener, IMixedRealityInputHandler<Vector2>
{
    public MixedRealityInputAction navigationAction;
    public float multiplier = 5f;

    private Vector3 delta = Vector3.zero;
    public void OnInputChanged(InputEventData<Vector2> eventData)
    {
        float horiz = eventData.InputData.x;
        float vert = eventData.InputData.y;
        if (eventData.MixedRealityInputAction == navigationAction)
        {
            delta = CameraCache.Main.transform.TransformDirection(new Vector3(horiz, 0, vert) * multiplier);
        }
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (delta.sqrMagnitude > 0.01f)
        {
            MixedRealityPlayspace.Transform.Translate(delta);
        }
    }

    protected override void RegisterHandlers()
    {
        CoreServices.InputSystem.RegisterHandler<MRPlayspaceMover>(this);
    }

    protected override void UnregisterHandlers()
    {
        CoreServices.InputSystem.UnregisterHandler<MRPlayspaceMover>(this);
    }
}
```

I used the following controller mapping to have dpad and thumbstick hook up to the navigation action:
[image]

Then I created a new gameobject, attached the MRPlayspaceMover script, and assigned the "navigation action" field:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked a treat, my only issue now is the camera passes through a vertical face of terrain collider? I have logged an issue in the MRTK GitHub but was wondering if you know a solution (other than putting up walls of box colliders)?

Comment: I would probably use colliders and then in adjust the delta to zero if the camera was near those colliders (e.g. using Physics.CheckSphere), or use some basic heurisitcs like set delta to 0 if it would make the camera move out of some predefined region.

Comment: Hi Julia, any chance you could give me some more guidance this has broken in MRTK 2.1.0 and we (Teacher & students) can't get navigation working? With the WMR controller D Pad or Joystick. It was so easy in RC1 but broke in 2.0.0 and 2.1.0 ? We have it as an issue in GITHUB but it's in the backlog and we really need it for a project that is being launched in a week. https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/5817